# "Error: socket hang up" in ChatBot created by Bot Builder

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have an error that shows frequently in a ChatBot created using Bot Builder Node.js SDK, here it is in details :

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Comment: Can you share the code that gets this error?  This doesn't look BotFramework specific.

Comment: I don't have a specific code that fires the error. I forgot to mention that I use DirectLine channel to communicate with the ChatBot. I think that is where communication through socket is being used.

Comment: Can you catch this error, and reconnect the socket? If you think this is an issue with the BotBuilder, please post on the gitgub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues